# Segmentation fault in iterative summation

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

Write a program to read an integer number and keep on adding the digits till
we get a number with a single digit. For example, 7976 yields an output of 2
`(7976 - - t 29 - - t 11 - - t 2)`.

For this, your `main()` function must call the function `sumdigits(0)` to solve
the problem, and then print the final result.

I have solved this problem and the logic is correct, I am not getting any output When i give my input it just move to next line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

sumdigits(int x)
{
  int n = x;
  int y = 0;

  while(n>0) {
    y = y + n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
  }
  return y;
}

int main(void)
{
 int a;

 scanf("%d",&a);

 while(a>10) {
   a=sumdigits(a);
 }

 printf("%d",a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with this line

```
scanf("%d",a);
```

It should be

```
scanf("%d", &a);
//----------^  use &
```